# Why is this C code section flagged as bad?

Tags: c

I am new to c. I come across this section of code in C, it's flagged as a bad code. Not sure why it's bad and any suggestions for improvement?

The original code is from this link:

https://pastebin.com/r2rTN6Zf

```
typedef struct {
    bool is_married;
    uint8_t age;
    uint8_t num_children;
} personal_info;

int lookup_personal_info(char *first_name, void *last_name, uint8_t (*sin)[9], const struct **info_out)
{
    // Sanity check.
    if (!first_name || !last_name || !sin)
        return false;

    char *initials[3] = { first_name[0], last_name[1] };

    // Allocate space for the output.
    personal_info *data = malloc(sizeof(struct personal_info));
    if (!data)
        goto fail;

    // Look up the personal info by initials.
    bool is_ok = database_lookup(initials, &data);
    if (is_ok)
        goto fail;

    // Assign the found data to the output parameter.
    *info_out = (personal_info *) data;

    // Success!
    return true;

fail:
    data = NULL;
    free(data);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is far too broad and opinion based for here. Poor use of `goto` and freeing a null pointer are what stands out though.

Comment: One odd thing is `if (is_ok) goto fail;` Probably meant `!is_ok`

Comment: What do you mean "bad?" Bad as in it fails to compile? Bad as in it fails a code review? Bad as in it doesn't do what you think it does? Bad as in it doesn't satisfy the requirements given to you? Bad as in it's inefficient? Bad as in it's doing things in ways that yourself or others doesn't deem "good?" Bad as in it's hard to read? etc.

Comment: Flagged by whom? How did you "come across" this code? What is your connection to / interest in the code - why do you need to know what's bad about it when it's not your code (and who told you that someone else's code is bad and why)? If you don't know C well enough to see what's bad about this code, why bother with this code rather than continuing to learn C until you have a better understanding of it? This almost seems like a "find the mistakes in this piece of code"-type homework assignment.

Comment: What are the prototypes and function declarations for the function `database_lookup()`?

Comment: Obviously not working code. Seems to be some sort of "How many defects/code smells can you spot? I think @sepp2k has it right.

Comment: thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a pointer to `NULL` before calling `free` on it makes the call to `free` benign (i.e. does nothing).

If you have a static analysis tool in your IDE that checks for and probably incorrect code, I wouldn't be surprised that it got picked up by it.

The idiomatic way to call `free` safely is to set the `free`-d pointer to `NULL` *after* the call, not before.

Comment: I would even go as far as supposing that the person who write this piece of code _reversed_ the 2 lines in the `fail` case.
The person probably meant: 
`free(data); data = NULL;`

Comment: @fassn `data` will be automatically cleared when the function exits shortly after, there's no need to manually clear it.

Comment: @Schwern The pointer itself will be cleared when it goes out of scope; the actual memory on the heap will remain until either it is freed or until (at least) the program terminates

Comment: @GovindParmar Yes, `free(data)` is necessary. `data = NULL` is not.

Comment: @Schwern The reason people frequently set pointers to `NULL` immediately after `free`ing them is to prevent “double free” bugs. It’s a good habit to have even if you’re being redundant by placing the assignment to `NULL` at the end of a scope.

Answer (score 2):

Any decent [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) will flag numerous problems with this code. Here's what the one provided with [Atom editor](https://atom.io/) found, plus what I eyeballed.

```
int lookup_personal_info(char *first_name, void *last_name, uint8_t (*sin)[9], const struct **info_out)
```

- `last_name` is declared `void *` but used as a `char *`
- `const struct **info_out` declares an anonymous struct. It should be `personal_info **info_out`
- The function returns a `bool` not an `int`.
- `sin` is never used except to check it's passed in.

```
    if (!first_name || !last_name || !sin)
        return false;
```

- Passing in a null pointer is probably a bug by the caller. This silently ignores that bug making it difficult to find. It should raise an error.
- It forgets to check `info_out`.

```
    char *initials[3] = { first_name[0], last_name[1] };
```

- This is an array of character pointers being initialized with `char`. It should be `char initials[3]`.
- It is not null terminated. Maybe it doesn't have to be, but I wouldn't risk that.
- `last_name` is declared `void *` yet used as a `char *`.
- It's using the first character of `first_name` as an initial, that makes sense, but why the second... thing... in `last_name`?

```
    personal_info *data = malloc(sizeof(struct personal_info));
```

`struct personal_info` is not a type, the type is `personal_info`.

```
    *info_out = (personal_info *) data;
```

`info_out` was incorrectly declared as an anonymous struct. It should be `personal_info **info_out`. Then no type cast is necessary.

```
    bool is_ok = database_lookup(initials, &data);
    if (is_ok)
        goto fail;
```

The check is backwards.

The use of `goto` is justified to ensure proper cleanup on error. It's probably included in the example as a red herring.

```
fail:
    data = NULL;
    free(data);

    return true;
```

- `free` is called after nulling out `data` leaking memory.
- There's no need to set `data` to `NULL`, it's local to the function which will shortly exit.
- Both failure and success return `true`.

Comment: An editor is not a linter. :P A linter is not a SAT, a SAT is not hooman, and a hooman is not a cat and cat is not an editor... :P

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make much sense to me.  Why free a `NULL` pointer...

```
fail:
    data = NULL;
    free(data);
```